# Get Quote In Observer

Tags: magento2

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class SaveOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
         // $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
         $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getEvent()->getQuote();

        $order->setData('shippingaccntno', $quote->getShippingCarrearAccountNo());
        $order->setData('dropdown', $quote->getDropDown());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

but its not working am getting error  `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQuote()`

**update:-**

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="extra_shipping_cost" instance="vendor\module\Observer\SaveOrderObserver" />
    </event>
```

Comment: Hi Pramod, the given details are not enough to advise on the issue in your code. Which event you are observing here?

Comment: am sharing my event code please check updated question

Comment: You can not call getEvent() on checkout session

Answer (score 0):

**Please check below code.**

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\EXTENSION\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class AddtoCart implements ObserverInterface {

    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product */
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i have also used the same code as a reference but its not working in my case

Comment: Please check in my code getEvent() is not there.
I checked in my local PC and it is working for me so I provide it. Still if not working then I will find another and post it.

Comment: na its not working

Comment: Ok I will post some other answer if I find.

Answer (score 0):

The event you are observing is firing from: `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::submitQuote()` method. It looks like this:

```
$this->eventManager->dispatch(
    'sales_model_service_quote_submit_before',
    [
         'order' => $order,
         'quote' => $quote
    ]
);
```

So in your observer, you can access your order like this:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

and the quote you can access like this:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
```

Comment: i have already tried that

Comment: it will surely give you a quote instance. 100% guarantee. do some debug there, if you are not getting quote. Log data in your observer. `get_class($quote)` will print Quote class name in your log.